# How can I execute a stage when a Merge Request is merged or closed?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I want to execute a certain stage when the Merge Request is merged or if if it's closed manually, basically I want to run at the end of CI and only if the user clicks Merge or if the MR is closed. For that I have this stage:

```
clean-environment:
  stage: deploy
  script: 
    - echo clean
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    action: stop
```

However, Gitlab is executing this stage every time that I make a commit. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `when: manual` to the job. GitLab will trigger the manual job when the MR is closed, as described in [stop an environment when a merge request is closed](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#stop-an-environment-when-a-merge-request-is-merged-or-closed).

Note the use of `when: manual` in the example from the docs:

```yaml
stop_review:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Remove review app"
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    action: stop
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      when: manual
```